# IUPAC nomenclature of alicyclic compound with an equal number of cyclic and acyclic carbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

In this compound there are three cyclic and three acyclic carbons. Even the substituent comes on the 2nd position in both cases. So, should the main chain be the *cyclic* one, since there is a rule that cyclic has a priority over acyclic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [current IUPAC recommendations (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001), for the preferred IUPAC name, a ring has seniority over a chain. Therefore, the given structure is a propylcyclopropane. (However, the IUPAC recommendations allow that the context may favour the chain.)

The two prefixes of cyclopropane (chloro- and 2-bromopropyl-) are arranged alphabetically. Thus, the name is **1-(2-bromopropyl)-2-chlorocyclopropane.**

[image: 1-(2-bromopropyl)-2-chlorocyclopropane]